# Can I use this material for tayammum?

Tags: wudu

Can I use this type of earthen unglazed product for tayammum though it doesnt have dust over it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tayammum is valid if done using anything that comes from the face of the earth, such as dust, mud, rocks, sand and clay, because Allaah says (interpretation of the meaning):

> perform Tayammum with clean Earth
>
> (al-Nisa’ 4:43)

It is permissible to do tayammum on walls or vessels made of clay, so long as they are not painted. If they are painted, tayammum is not valid unless there is dust on them. You can put some dirt or sand in a vessel and use that for tayammum.